# Sending values from ReactForm to Django view

Tags: python, python-3.x, reactjs, django

I have a react form as follows:

```js
render(){
return({
<Form role="form" method="post">
  
  <Input type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect" >
                        <option value="2011">2011</option>
                        <option value="2012">2012</option>
                        <option value="2013">2013</option>
                        <option>2014</option>
                        <option>2015</option>
                        </Input>
</Form>)}
}
```

I have the following view in Django:

```
class FormView(APIView):
    def get(self, request,*args, **kwargs):
        
       
        return Response({"keywords":applyFormScan(2013)})
```

I am trying to obtain the value 2013 from the react form.I have tried post method but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please, share the code you tried and did'nt worked. Also, your React code is incomplete: share full class/function.

Comment: @emi This is pretty much my code.nothing else except import package

Comment: `I have tried post method but it doesn't work for me.` What did you tried?

Comment: @emi Instead of get in views.py, I tried post

Comment: How do you access this endpoint from React?